# Writing CLS compliant code in F#

Tags: f#

I am very new to F# and I started to write my functional wrapper on top of OpenGL. I also intend to use it to write a graphics engine which should have interop with all .Net languages.

But it is hard to find information about which code constructs in F# are not CLS compliant.

For example I already know of a few that are not CLS compliant:

- static type constrains
- tupleless functions
- probably `'T list and Seq`
- maybe even union types

How do I know what features of F# are not CLS compliant?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [CLSCompliant attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.clscompliantattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=fsharp#code-snippet-1). It will guarantee that your code is CLS-Compliant at compile time.

Like this:

```
module myProject.AssemblyInfo

open System

[<assembly: CLSCompliant(true)>]

do()
```

*Source: [Mike-Ward.Net: Learning F#–Assembly Level Attributes](http://mike-ward.net/blog/post/00761/learning-fndashassembly-level-attributes)*

For a more complete discussion of the CLSCompliant attribute, see [C# Corner: Making Your Code CLS Compliant](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/avmahesh/making-your-code-cls-compliant/)