# How do I make sure an identifier is accessible from any .Net/CLI language?

Tags: .net, f#

Compared to C# ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/lexical-structure#identifiers ), F# allows a broader set of characters in identifier names ( http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/ ), including `'`, and almost anything is allowed if you use double backticks:

> Any sequence of characters that is enclosed in double-backtick marks (``` `` `` ```),
>   excluding newlines, tabs, and double-backtick pairs
>   themselves, is treated as an identifier. Note that when an identifier
>   is used for the name of a types, union type case, module, or
>   namespace, the following characters are not allowed even inside
>   double-backtick marks:
>
> `.`, `+`, `$`, `&`, `[`, `]`, `/`, `\\`, `*`,
>   `\"`, `` ` ``

But this presents problems for interop between the languages -- it may be impossible to statically refer to some entities defined in F# code from C#, but only access them dynamically using reflection.

Is there a single set of naming rules that can guarantee a namespace, type, etc. can be referenced in any CLI language? And are there restrictions on what is allowed in .Net's internal representation of these names, or is any arbitrary Unicode that makes it through a language's parser allowed?

Comment: Mark your code as CLS Compliant. See answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028833/writing-cls-compliant-code-in-f?rq=1